Cassandra service produces no logs whatsoever when trying to start
Time and again I come across this issue where I edit some cassandra config file, and cassandra service does not start anymore.
How can I understand why service cassandra start  doesn't start Cassandra?
If I run /etc/init.d/cassandra it starts fine.
journalctl -u cassandra.service has no logs at all.
/var/log/cassandra/system.log, /var/log/cassandra/debug.log, /var/log/syslog have no logs either.
When I execute service cassandra status the status is "active (exited)"
I have the latest cassandra version installed via apt-get on debian.

Not the best solution, because it's not recommended to run cassandra as root, due to potential security problems. But in order to make it run temporarily (and make sure that it was a permission issue indeed) I had to run it as root and chmod -R 777 all cassandra folders:
/etc/cassandra
/var/lib/cassandra
/var/log/cassandra
(While doing chmod and before running cassandra again you have to make sure cassandra is not running via ps aux | grep cassandra)
In order to run it as root I had to sudo systemctl edit --full cassandra and add User=root into the [Service] section. And WantedBy=multi-user.target into the [Install] section.
Now cassandra.service looks like this:
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/cassandra
Description=LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=network-online.target
After=nss-lookup.target
After=time-sync.target
After=ntp.service
After=mdadm.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root                       # Added this line
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop

[Install]                       # Added this line
WantedBy=multi-user.target      # Added this line

How I figured out that this was a permissions issue? I ran cassandra as a non-root user by running the cassandra command. This ran cassandra in the foreground and I saw AccessDenied exceptions.

It's not clear to me from your post whether service cassandra start has ever worked before. I bring this up is because on systems that use systemd, service might be disabled and you will need to start Cassandra using systemctl, for example:
$ sudo systemctl start cassandra

Interestingly, you ran journalctl to check but it only works for displaying the logs for journald -- the logging service for systemd.
I would suggest whether your system is using systemd for running services and try using systemctl. Cheers!
UPDATE - I forgot to point out the obvious things which are:

incorrect service name, and
insufficient permissions.

I mentioned the service name because you misspelled cassandra in:

... why service casasandra start doesn't start ...

Also, you need to be root to start the service, usually with sudo access:
$ sudo service cassandra start

Without root access, a regular user won't have the right permissions so usually messages won't get persisted in the logs.

Yes, it absolutely worked before. I run service as root, running through systemctl has the same effect, there are no logs, no anything. If it's a permission issue then it should output which folder/file it is unable to access, but there is nothing.

This really sounds like it's environmental, not a Cassandra issue per se. Check that the service is enabled, with chkconfig or equivalent, for example. If there are security apps installed on the server, disable them temporarily so you could isolate the problem. Something on the server is preventing the service from running and writing to logs. Cheers!

Yea, the service is enabled. It's an permissions issue. I figured it out yesterday. I temporarily did chmod -R 777 on /etc/cassandra, /var/lib/cassandra and /var/log/cassandra. Also edited cassandra.service via systemctl edit --full cassandra and added User=root into the [Service] section and WantedBy=multi-user.target into the [Install] section. Alas, the logs not getting written is another issue that I haven't figured out.
